# Why does my "Popup window" not showing for the second time on click?

Tags: html, css, popup, window

I have above code work fine here ( if i run code ) but it causing me error on my website.
What's happening is that on first time click on all links works fine but when i try to click second time then it shows blank page and you can't click anywhere on page so either i have to refresh or click back button.

```css
.overlay {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  transition: opacity 500ms;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
    overflow:hidden;
  z-index:9999999;
}
.overlay:target {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

.popup {
  margin: 70px auto;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 30%;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 5s ease-in-out;

}

.popup h2 {
  margin-top: 0;
  color: #333;
  font-family: Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
}
.popup .close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 30px;
  transition: all 200ms;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
}
.popup .close:hover {
  color: #06D85F;
}
.popup .content {
  max-height: 30%;
  overflow: auto;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 700px){

  .popup{
    width: 70%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div style="clear:both; height:23px; font-size:9px; color:#0033FF; text-align:right; margin-right:11px;"><a href="#1" >View</a></div>
                          <div id="1" class="overlay">
 <div class="popup">
  <h2>pop up window one </h2>
  <a class="close" href="#" >&times;</a>
  <div class="content">
   this is my pop up window 1
  </div>
 </div>
</div>


<div style="clear:both; height:23px; font-size:9px; color:#0033FF; text-align:right; margin-right:11px;"><a href="#2" >View</a></div>
                          <div id="2" class="overlay">
 <div class="popup">
  <h2>pop up window one </h2>
  <a class="close" href="#" >&times;</a>
  <div class="content">
   this is my pop up window 1
  </div>
 </div>
</div>



<div style="clear:both; height:23px; font-size:9px; color:#0033FF; text-align:right; margin-right:11px;"><a href="#3" >View 3</a></div>
                          <div id="3" class="overlay">
 <div class="popup">
  <h2>pop up window one </h2>
  <a class="close" href="#" >&times;</a>
  <div class="content">
   this is my pop up window 1
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it is working perfectly as desired.

Comment: Its not working on my page just click few times on view link. https://www.sublimefurnishings.co.uk/629/ruby_flexi/diamond_package.html

Comment: Try to hard refresh your page by pressing F5.

Comment: if you click more than once on same link, then screen goes stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your instructions I got that there is a problem with **theme.js** file in your website.

whenever you are clicking that close **"x"** button of popup a function in that file at **line number 105** triggers and adds a inline css in your popup and reduces the opacity of the popup div to **"opacity:0"**.

**solution:** you can just change that class name and remove the click even as a temporary solution. or you can edit theme.js file and reduce your code and get better performance...

choice is yours
I hope that this will help you. or else you can tell me for any kind of help!
Thank you!

Happy Coding!!!

Comment: You are genius mate. it has sorted out my problem. I just changed class name from close to shut and it worked perfectly. well done. sorry can't give you rating from 0 to 1 as i dont have much ranking. however i have ticked on the sign to green as it is solved.

Answer (score 0):

It is working perfectly in Stack overflow code snippet. 
i think there might be some problem with your local environment.

Although if u need any kind of help, feel free to ask me!

Thank you!
Happy Coding!

Comment: Its not working on my page. just click on view more than once on this page. https://www.sublimefurnishings.co.uk/198/hmo_furniture_packages/gold_hmo.html

Comment: exactly where do i need t click in this website?

Comment: where you can see text link "view" below every 6 boxes on right hand side (if your are on desktop pc)

Comment: see my next answer for the exact problem

Comment: it's on and hope that would help you!